# parsing xml with Google Aps script

Tags: xml-parsing, google-apps-script

I have to parse short xml messages received as attachement of mails.
In the documentation about XML (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/service_xml) some examples could be useful.

Thanks a lot if you send me some hints to help me parsing (exemples, bits of code ...

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [tutorial on Parsing XML with apps script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/XML_tutorial)